# Wire hangers under connector

Tags: connector, soldering, automotive

I have noticed small hangers under the Rosenberg HSD connector:

What is the purpose of these? 
I can only guess it's solder paste storage for pin-in-paste technology but on the other hand, it's quite thin.

Can someone confirm?

[image]

Comment: That isn't a surface mount component, it just looks like whoever soldered it on there used *way too much* solder/heat and it leeched down some tracks possibly under the soldermask breaking it away.

Comment: there was a question about these types of "spikes" or "tabs" on a circuit board about a month back ... those are intentional ... I'll see if i can find the post, because i don't remember the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the edges of the hooks are straight it might be a mask opening added by the designer, as you said to access the pad with solder (manual soldering), although the component seems to be PTH so it would be accessible from the other side.

If the edges are dented or uneven then overheating could have snapped the solder mask, especially on traces too thin for their current.

Answer (score 0):

Could just be some traces sans solder mask that the designer added in order to be able to stick a probe.

If that's the original soldering, it looks like it was done after the SMT soldering and probably by hand, based on the enormous deposits of flux around the pins, so not paste/pin technology.

Comment: It's an automotive part, my guess at least 5M volume, hand soldering is not possible in that case. The other option would be selective soldering.